# How to implement __missing__ for pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, oop, pandas, dataframe

I would like to implement `__missing__` (same behaviour than in `dict`) without overwritting `__getitem__` for a subclass of `pandas.DataFrame`. Here is what I tried so far:

```
import pandas as pd

class Bar0(pd.DataFrame):
    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return Bar0


    def __missing__(self, key):
        print('Call __missing__ from {} with key'.format(type(self), key))
        return key


class Bar1(Bar0):
    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return Bar1


    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print('Call __getitem__ from {} with key {}'.format(type(self), key))
        try:
            return super().__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            return self.__missing__(key)


class Bar2(dict, Bar0):
    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return Bar2


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Bar0.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        dict.__init__(self)

        self.__getitem__ = Bar0.__getitem__


class Bar3(Bar0, dict):
    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return Bar3


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Bar0.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        dict.__init__(self)

        self.__getitem__ = Bar0.__getitem__

for bar in (Bar0, Bar1, Bar2, Bar3):
    foo = bar({'a': [1]})
    foo['a']
    try:
        foo['b']
    except KeyError:
        print('Raised KeyError for {}'.format(type(foo)))
    print('')
```

which resulted in:

```
Raised KeyError for <class '__main__.Bar0'> // Didn't call __missing__

Call __getitem__ from <class '__main__.Bar1'> with key a
Call __getitem__ from <class '__main__.Bar1'> with key b // Did call __missing__ but also __getitem__ 
Call __missing__ from <class '__main__.Bar1'> with key

Call __missing__ from <class '__main__.Bar2'> with key // Didn't even find 'a' - I guess it searches __getitem__ from dict instead of pd.DataFrame
Call __missing__ from <class '__main__.Bar2'> with key

Raised KeyError for <class '__main__.Bar3'> // Didn't call __missing__
```

For the case it matters:

- Python: 3.5
- Pandas: 0.19.2+0.g825876c.dirty
- OS: RHEL 6

Comment: `__missing__` is specifically something `dict.__getitem__` looks for. It's not a general thing.

Comment: Assigning to `self.__getitem__` has no effect on indexing operations. Also, what was `_constructor` supposed to be? Python doesn't call its constructors `_constructor`.

Comment: @user2357112, thx for your comments. Concerning `_constructor` (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/internals.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures), seems like you are right with asigning `__getitem__`. I'm still a bit puzzled by the difference of assigning an attribute and defining it. Since I would assume that the method itself is just a function pointer attribute pointing to the function.

Comment: Looks like `_constructor` is indeed a thing Pandas recognizes. Google didn't find it, since Google sucks at symbols. As for assigning to `self.__getitem__`, Python skips the instance dict when performing special method lookup, so it skips the `__getitem__` entry in the instance dict.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Do you know any way to implement a __missing__ for the DataFrame?

Comment: Override `__getitem__`. `__missing__` is a red herring here.